# Find the maximum integer, that can be obtained by permutation of numbers of an arbitrary three-digit positive integer n (100<=n<=999)

Tags: java, permutation

Find the maximum integer, that can be obtained by permutation of numbers of an arbitrary three-digit positive integer n (100<=n<=999).

````
public static int maxNum(int n) {
int j , k ,l, result;
String  q, z, y ,w;

    do {
        j = n % 10;
        k = n % 100/ 10;
        l = n % 1000 /100;

        q =Integer.toString(k);
        z =Integer.toString(j);
        y =Integer.toString(l);
        w= (q+z+y);
        result =Integer.parseInt(w);

        break;
    } while (n >=100 && n<=999);

    return result;
}


``` input
````

165

```
output 

651    

input 123 

output 
321
```

Comment: The `while` loop just loops forever, and none of this code even tries to find the highest number.

Comment: What's your question?  Does your program work? If not, what goes wrong?

Comment: Trying to find the.maximum number  that can be obtained by permutation  for instance if the input is  165 output should be 651 incase the question  is not clear  am quite new the program  language was practicing conditional exercise came across this question

Comment: You've got the individual digits in `j`, `k` and `l`. There is no need to "make permutations" to find the biggest number. What you need to do is SORT those digits in descending order (largest to smallest). This could be done in various fancy ways using all kinds of sort algorithms, but since you are limited to 3 digit numbers it can be brute forced with a series of if/else statements, which is probably what they were going for.

Comment: Are you allowed to use built-in sort methods, or do you need to do it manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to order the digits in descending order and then build up the 3 digit value accordingly.

```
- 152 - 1, 5, 2
- in ascending order is 5, 2, 1
- ( 10 * 5) + 2) * 10) + 1 = 521
```

Here is one way to do it with streams.

```
Random r = new Random();
```

- generate  a value between 100 and 999 inclusive
- convert to a String and split the digit characters
- sort in descending order
- convert each integer to a numeric digit
- and use reduce to get the largest number

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     int value = r.nextInt(100, 1000);
     int max = Arrays.stream(Integer.toString(value).split(""))
             .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
             .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
             .reduce(0, (a, b) -> a * 10 + b);
     System.out.println(value + " -> " + max);
}
```

prints something like the following:

```
105 -> 510
694 -> 964
983 -> 983
432 -> 432
792 -> 972
868 -> 886
979 -> 997
839 -> 983
803 -> 830
911 -> 911
```

You can also do it without sorting and using just a single while loop.

- the while loop simply replaces the sorting by ordering the 3 digits in decreasing order.
- then `max1, max2, and max3` are combined as previously explained.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     int value = r.nextInt(100,1000);
     int max1 = 0,max2 = 0,max3 = 0;
     int temp = value; // save for later printing.
     while (value > 0) {
         int d = value % 10; // get last digit of value
      
         if (max1 < d) {
             max3 = max2;
             max2 = max1;
             max1 = d;
         }
         else if (max2 < d) {
             max3 = max2;
             max2 = d;
         }
         else if (max3 < d) {
             max3 = d;
         }
         value /= 10;  // expose next digit
     }
     
     int max = (((max1*10)+max2)*10)+max3;
     System.out.println(temp + " -> " + max);     
 }
```